# How to optimally display over 500k EOA wallets' daily balances spanning three years back?

Tags: wallets, json-rpc, rpc, eth-call

I would like to display over 500k EOA wallets' daily balances spanning three years back and wonder if there is a more efficient method than using `eth_call` and `balanceOf` 500k times per day for three years to retrieve daily wallet balances from an Ethereum RPC node?

And if there isn't, what's the best RPC provider to go for this operation considering throughput, latency and price? Does it make sense to setup and run own archive node?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In tackling the challenge of efficiently retrieving and displaying daily balances for over 500,000 EOAs spanning three years on Ethereum, a combination of smart contract interactions, batch requests, and a well-structured PostgreSQL database can be used. Here's a breakdown of the approach:

1. **Batch Requests and Smart Contract Use:**

   - Utilize batch requests to query balances of multiple EOAs in a single network call, minimizing the number of API requests.
   - Alternatively, deploy a smart contract with a function that accepts an array of EOA addresses and returns their balances (either native or ERC20) at the block of the `eth_call`.
2. **PostgreSQL Database Structure:**

   - **Accounts Table:** This table stores a record for each EOA with a unique identifier and Ethereum address.
   - **Balance Changes Table:** This table records every balance change event for the EOAs, storing the account identifier, the new balance, block number, and timestamp of the change.
3. **Efficient Data Storage and Retrieval:**

   - Record balance changes in the Balance Changes Table only when a change in balance is detected, significantly reducing redundant data.
   - To retrieve the latest balance for an EOA at a specific block number, query the Balance Changes Table for the most recent entry before or at that block.
4. **Data Retrieval Frequency:**

   - Since your requirement is for daily snapshots, you can schedule your data retrieval (either via batch requests or smart contract calls) to run once daily, thus capturing the end-of-day balances for each EOA.
5. **Data Resolution Considerations:**

   - **Daily Snapshots:** Retrieving balances at the start of each day provides a daily snapshot but lacks finer resolution for balance changes that occur throughout the day.
   - **Block-by-Block Resolution:** For higher resolution, you could opt to fetch balances at every block. To efficiently index and store this data, implement a system that intelligently records balance changes only when they occur (i.e., if an account's balance doesn't change over 'N' blocks, you only store the balance at the block where it changed).
   - **Intra-Block Resolution:** Even with block-level resolution, you won't capture balance changes within individual blocks. Achieving this would require a system that tracks balance changes caused by transactions within each block, which is more complex and resource-intensive.
6. **Choosing an Ethereum Client or RPC Provider:**

   - Opt for a reliable Ethereum client or RPC provider capable of handling high request volumes. Consider factors like rate limits, response times, and costs.
7. **Data Visualization:**

   - Utilize data visualization tools that can effectively present large datasets, enabling you to analyze and display the balance trends over the specified period.

In this setup, the database design plays a crucial role in efficiently managing and querying balance data. By recording balance changes only when they occur, you minimize storage requirements and improve query performance. This approach offers a practical solution for tracking and displaying EOA balances over an extended time frame, making it both resource-efficient and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this tool for precisely this reason:

https://github.com/ChristianPapathanasiou/ETH-sniper

It checks 500 addresses per transaction. All you need to do is deploy the smart contract on Ethereum or Polygon.

The tool generates an array of addresses to check and prepares the transaction to send to the smart contract.

The smart contract does a balanceOf(address) for each address in the array.

If an address has a positive balance, the contract emits an event which is observable on the blockchain.

As you can appreciate this will cost you gas, so to avoid this, I  have integrated Tenderly simulations into the program to  check 500 addresses at a time.

Of course you can scale this to check more addresses by simply increasing the array size in the contract itself eg below from 500 to 1000+

```
def getUSDCBalances(addresses: address[500]) -> uint256:
```

Python code needs small changes to check the addresses you have in mind rather than randomly generated ones that it currently checks.

Contract can also be easily modified so it becomes multi token check eg currently it checks for USDC balance but you can update it so that it checks each address for multiple token balances and emits corresponding events if found.

Modifying Tenderly API call you can also simulate the blockchain "as it was" at a certain point in time (which will allow you to run the same program eg at a time period 3 years back to see what the balances were at that point in time).

However, you can also use something like this as a "data feed server" so that it runs eg once a day collects balances and then stores them somewhere and you get a daily snapshot going forward.